# IRF520 as a relay driver

Tags: relay, esp8266, esp32

I am trying to use IRF520 as a relay driver for ESP32, but by reason unknown it does not works. I have replaced it twice with a new ones, but yet it keep not working.
I have 3V on the ESP32 pin when the state is HIGH and 0V when the state is LOW.
I am using the circuit below:

[image]

- Why the IRF520 never trigger the relay ?

Comment: Look at Figure 1 in the [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/91017.pdf).

Comment: Then go search for logic level FETs with Vt=1V or make a 3V to 12V level shifter using any NPN.  or simply use any NPN to drive the coil instead of FET.  Why don't they teach students that Vgs(th) is just the very early threshold of conduction at < 1mA and that has a 50% tolerance. All the old Enh FETS were 2~4V for Vt. Also if it starts with IRF it is the old style.

Comment: So.. is there some other FET transistor I can replace it ? The relay is consuming about 50 mA.

Comment: Look for "logic level mosfet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed is that threshold voltage for IRF520 is 4V. A MOSFET won't start conducting heavily (or completely turn ON) until threshold voltage is reached.
You are using 3.3 volts which is obviously less than that.You need a separate drive circuit or just use another transistor with a lower threshold voltage, say 3 volts.

Comment: Actually, a MOSFET **will** start conducting below the threshold voltage. And a transistor with a threshold of 3V might not provide **enough current** at the measured threshold voltage. I think this answer oversimplifies MOSFET behavior to the point that it may do more harm than good.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: And if you look closely at the drain current at which the threshold voltage is determined (250 uA in this case), you'll find that it's far too low to drive something like a relay.

Comment: There is some confusion here. 4V is the _maximum_ threshold voltage of an IRF520. A FET with _maximum_ threshold of 3V will probably have a nominal value of around 2V, so it might work but is not guaranteed. To be sure, you should choose a device specified for 3V or 2.5V Gate drive.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It could be that the particular device @AnapSinahputra is using is having threshold voltage at its maximum limit of 4 Volts.

Comment: oh gods. i didnt know this! :O Thank You !

Comment: What other MOSFET transistor I can use ? ( looking for cheap and accessible one if possible )

Comment: Try swapping with another mosfet of same part number, preferably from a different batch or manufacturer. Sometimes its just the individual variation of devices. On time I got an hfe reading of 800 for a bjt rated only 300!

Comment: I see you are driving the mosfet with pin from the esp directly even though you have a separate 12 volt supply. Use a simple optocoupler say pc817, its cheap, and you can drive the same MOSFET in no time.